# About your merging accounts facility.

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I'm [user 128932](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/128932/) and [user 201044](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/201044/) and asked to merge accounts. Now it expired and I can't use the reputation points from account 128932. What do I do?

Comment: (1) What expired?  (2) do you still have access to both accounts?

Comment: I have only 201044 right now and can't use points from 128932. How can I use points from 128932 which is mine too?

Comment: Do you remember how you used to login to your account 128932? (With Google or some other OpenID service?)

Comment: The account 128932 is 'tied' to my former gmail address that isn't working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ["contact us" form](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) linked in the footer and select "I need to merge user profiles" as the subject. That form is handled by SE employees and they are the only ones with the ability to merge users.

You will have to demonstrate in some way that the other account was yours, otherwise anyone could just hijack accounts of other people. But that will be explained in the response from SE.